# Are there any other branch of mathematical philosophy?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

Are there any other branch of mathematical philosophy?

I am refer to the mathematical logic, are there any other branch of mathematical philosophy?

For example, philosophical graph theory would be use to describe the connection between philosophy, and philosophy group theory will be use to describe the property of philosophy within a group

Comment: You might want to check [this](https://www.coursera.org/course/mathphil) introductory course on **Mathematical Philosophy**.

Comment: I would propose that all of mathematics is in fact philosophy, and not science or anything else.  It is the exploration of human intuition unfettered by actual data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean the philosophy of mathematics. In my mind, it is basically just a part of philosophy with lots of (interesting) questions, rather than having lots of sub-branches, as something like ethics does (which is quite diverse).

In the philosophy of mathematics, people talk about things like:

- What would serve as a good foundation of mathematics? For instance, research on how mathematics can be done constructively. (mathematical logic)
- What can one say about undecidable statements in mathematics? (i.e. can they be given a truth value, or not. This is also mathematical logic).
- Can we give a better idea of what mathematical beauty means? (aesthetics)
- Is mathematics invented or discovered? (misc.)
- Why does physics need mathematics? (misc. / philosophy of science)

Unfortunately I fear that I probably haven't told you anything new so I apologize if this is the case.

Comment: What about mathematics of philosophy like we draw a flow chart for philosopher

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: For example, philosophical graph theory would be use to describe the connection between philosophy, and  philosophy group theory will be use to describe the property of philosophy within a group

Comment: In what sense is a [flow chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) mathematical?  I can see how you might use one to describe a mathematical process (or a philosophical process), but they aren't mathematical *per ser*.  Graph theory is a little more math-y -- or comp sci-y -- but that's a *reductive* technique for organizing information that already could be applied to anything (or nothing).  If you mean, is there a "philosophy of philosophy", yes, but arguably that's [the same thing as philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphilosophy#Terminology) to start with...